# Show view only if items are selected in list using EditButton and multiple selection in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code lets you select multiple items from a list and clear the selection list when a button is tapped. What I would like to be able to do is not show the `Deselect All` button unless there are items selected in the list or at least when in editing mode.

Is there a way to show a view only if items are selected? Or at least only when in edit mode?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var itemSelection = Set<String>()

    let names = [ "Orange", "Apple", "Grape", "Watermelon"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                List(names, id: \.self, selection: $itemSelection) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Item List")
                .toolbar {
                    EditButton()
                }
                
                Button("Deselect All"){
                    print("Items: \(itemSelection)")
                    itemSelection.removeAll()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a second way for you in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var itemSelection = Set<String>()

    let names = [ "Orange", "Apple", "Grape", "Watermelon"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                List(names, id: \.self, selection: $itemSelection) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Item List")
                .toolbar {
                    EditButton()
                }
                
                if !itemSelection.isEmpty {
                    
                    Button("Deselect All"){
                        print("Items: \(itemSelection)")
                        itemSelection.removeAll()
                    }
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
                    
                }

            }
            .animation(.default, value: itemSelection.isEmpty)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is second way for you with this advantage that if you select some items and then you did not deselect items, then app would consider that you do not wanted to have any selection anymore. In case you want have selection even after ending editing then the first answer is for you not this second answer here:

***PS: I found a strange bug, editMode is not readable or usable when we have NavigationView, therefore I defined a stand alone view for edit button.***

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var names: [String] = ["Orange", "Apple", "Grape", "Watermelon"]
    @State private var itemSelection = Set<String>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                List(names, id: \.self, selection: $itemSelection) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
                .navigationTitle("Item List")
                .toolbar { EditModeView(itemSelection: $itemSelection) }
                
                if !itemSelection.isEmpty {
                    
                    Button("Deselect All"){
                        print("Items: \(itemSelection)")
                        itemSelection.removeAll()
                    }
                    .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: itemSelection.isEmpty)
        }
    }
}

struct EditModeView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
    @Binding var itemSelection: Set<String>
    
    var body: some View {
        EditButton()
            .onChange(of: editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing, perform: { newValue in
                
                if let unwrappedNewValue: Bool = newValue, (!unwrappedNewValue) {
                    itemSelection.removeAll()
                }
                
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good examples. - I really like the animation you added to show/hide the button.